# Unable to start Tomcat7 on 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat7

I'm running a VirtualBox of a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 14.04. When attempting to run `sudo service tomcat7 start` I get the following message.

```
start-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/lib/jvm/java-t-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

It then returns saying the server has started.

After running `service tomcat7 status` I get the following:

```
Tomcat servlet engine is running with pid
```

Notice that there is no pid shown, which doesn't make any sense to me.

Regardless, this all ends up in the servlet not actually running when I attempt to navigate to localhost/.

I have no idea why it is looking for 64 bit java on a 32 bit install. I have everything else (to my knowledge) installed properly.
I've uninstalled/reinstalled tomcat and java to no avail.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe there's a lock file somewhere that you need to delete?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you run `startup.sh` from within `tomcat/bin`?

Comment: Wherever you've installed tomcat. I'm guessing now you've installed from apt? If so run: dpkg -L tomcat-package-name and it will list where it's installed tomcat

Comment: This is what I get 
`root@user-VirtualBox:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin# ./startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out’: No such file or directory
./catalina.sh: 385: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent`

Answer (score 0):

check the version of java using java -version. you will get the architecture of java. Make sure that you have installed the 32 bit jre properly. 
(My recommendation is to use oracle jre instead open jre). Try to download the tomcat from their [site](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) as .tar.gz. Extract it somewhere in your system. Locate the startup.sh script ,by default it will be present in bin folder of tomcat, and execute the script.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: hard to catch for a newbie

Comment: I have installed the jre by hand already. What's intriguing to me is that the tomcat script is looking for a 64 bit version. I opened up the script and it seems to be able to handle both 64 and 32 bit versions of java, but obviously something is amiss somewhere.

Comment: did you set the JRE_HOME variable properly. Check by executing echo $JRE_HOME. Check the version of jre. Because by default linux distributions contain openjre

Comment: JRE_HOME is set correctly, but the error still occurs

Comment: check the links just i've come across. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451047/service-tomcat7-start-fails-but-the-process-exists-and-tomcat-is-running?rq=1   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718980/solved-tomcat7-wont-start-up-on-ubuntu-clean-install-permission-denied?rq=1

Comment: Also check your tomcat logs what is the error while trying to start

Comment: @Shriram The first link is a different scenario from mine. He can get a response from Tomcat using wget, where as I cannot. Also if I run `tomcat7 status` mine returns that it is running, but does not return its pid. However, I can see the process and I know what its pid is. I've also tried installing tomcat manually, to no avail.

Comment: Interestingly, catalina.out has not updated since install. So I couldn't tell you what it's logging